# How to use appProperties in Google Drive api v3?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

How to set the app properties of a file using Google Drive v3 in java?

The reference says: "files.update with {'appProperties':{'key':'value'}}", but I don't understand how to apply that to my java code.

I've tried things like

```
file = service.files().create(body).setFields("id").execute();
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(DEVICE_ID_KEY, deviceId);
file.setAppProperties(properties);
service.files().update(file.getId(), file).setFields("appProperties").execute();
```

but then I get an error that  "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."

And to get the data:

```
File fileProperty = service.files().get(sFileId).setFields("appProperties").execute();
```

So how to set and get the properties for the file?
Thanks! :)

**Edit**
I tried

```
file = service.files().create(body).setFields("id").execute();
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put(DEVICE_ID_KEY, deviceId);
file.setAppProperties(properties);
service.files().update(file.getId(), file).execute();
```

but I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid this error on v3

```
"The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
```

when calling `update`, you need to create an empty `File` with the new changes and pass that to the `update` function.

I wrote this and other notes as a [v3 Migration Guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35143283/google-drive-api-v3-migration).

Answer (score 1):

The [Drive API client for Java v3](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/) indicates that the `File.setAppProperties` will require a `Hashmap<String,String>` parameter. Try to remove the `setFields("appProperties")` call since you are trying to overwrite `appProperties` itself (you're still calling Update at this time).

When retrieving `appProperties`, you'll just need to call [`getAppProperties`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getAppProperties()).

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried 
file = service.files().create(body).setFields("id").execute();

            Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

            properties.put(DEVICE_ID_KEY, deviceId);

            file.setAppProperties(properties);

            File fileProperty = service.files().update(file.getId(), file).execute(); 
but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    File fileMetadata = new File();       
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(YOUR_LOCAL_FILE_PATH);

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(YOUR_KEY, YOUR_VALUE); //can be filled with custom String
    fileMetadata.setAppProperties(map);     

    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(YOUR_IMPORT_FORMAT, filePath);
    File file = service.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
            .setFields("id, appProperties").
            .execute();
```

YOUR_IMPORT_FORMAT, fill this with the value in this link, https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads, there is explanation below the example code

setFields("id, appProperties"), fill this with the value in this link: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/migration, this the most important part I think, if you don't set the value in the setFields method your additional input will not be written

Answer (score 0):

With version v3, to add or update appProperties for an existing file and without this error:

```
"The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable."
```

You should do:

```
String fileId = "Your file id key here";
Map<String, String> appPropertiesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
appPropertiesMap.put("MyKey", "MyValue");
appPropertiesMap.put("MySecondKey", "any value");

//set only the metadata you want to change
//do not set "id" !!! You will have "The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable." error
File fileMetadata = new File();
fileMetadata.setAppProperties(appPropertiesMap);

File updatedFileMetadata = driveService.files().update(fileId, fileMetadata).setFields("id, appProperties").execute();
System.out.printf("Hey, I see my appProperties :-) %s \n", updatedFileMetadata.toPrettyString());
```